# If $G$ is group isomorphic to $H$, then ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Aut}(H)$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Firstly, I am aware this question has been asked on this site before. My issue is that I don't feel confident on my approach to the proof since other solutions use the concepts of conjugation.

Here is my approach to the proof.
Assume $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is an isomorphism. Let $\theta:{\rm Aut}(G) \rightarrow {\rm Aut}(H)$ by $\theta(\alpha)=\phi(\alpha)$, where $\alpha\in{\rm Aut}(G)$ be a function. I claim that $\theta$ is an isomorphism between ${\rm Aut}(G)$ and ${\rm Aut}(H)$.

Am I right?

Comment: What does $\phi(\alpha)$ mean?

Comment: If $\phi(\alpha)$ means applying $\phi$ to the output of $\alpha$, then you've produced a function $G \to H$, not a function $H \to H$.

Comment: You could rather try $\theta(\alpha)=\beta$, where $\beta(h)=\alpha(\phi^{-1}(h))$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yikes. Stupid mistake. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry for the lack of notation. Please read the second comment.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha Shouldn't it be $\theta(\alpha)(h)=\phi (\alpha(\phi^{-1}(h)))$? By your definition, the output of $\theta$ is not a function from $H\to H$, it is $H\to G$

Comment: @Riley Yeah, you are right. silly mistake

Comment: @GentGjonbalaj In case the conjugation is confusing you, remember that the idea is to create an automorphism $H\to H$ by converting the input to $G$, applying the automorphism, and then converting it back to $H$ again. The isomorphism $\phi$ can be seen as the "conversion".

Comment: The point is that isomorphisms amount to "renaming" the elements of $G$ by some other names, namely the element of $H$. So to show that any argument involving $G$ corresponds to the same argument involving $H$ you need to do a "translation." The way you "translate" an automorphism is by first translating from $H$ to $G$, then applying the automorphism, then translating back from $G$ to $H$.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, it's often useful to draw a diagram : you want to carry some structure of $G$ (an automorphism $\alpha$) to $H$ and you're not sure how to compose the morphisms, then simply draw :

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G @>{\phi}>> H;\\
@VVV^\alpha @VVV^\beta \\
G @>{\phi}>> H;
\end{CD}$

($\alpha$ is supposed to be on the leftmost arrow, if someone can help me fix this...)

This tells you that an automorphism that's naturally associated to $\alpha$, call it $\beta$, would satisfy $\beta\circ \phi = \phi\circ \alpha$, so $\beta = \phi\circ\alpha\circ \phi^{-1}$ seems like a good candidate.

Of course this is not a proof that this works, nor is it the only way to make it work, but this is a way of finding ideas, and it comes in handy more than once. Now you simply have to check that $\alpha \mapsto \phi\circ \alpha\circ\phi^{-1}$  is an isomorphism $Aut(G)\to Aut(H)$ !

Comment: I am not sure the xymatrix package works here. You could just use an array?

Comment: @user1729 : could you explain how one does that ?

Comment: Begin and end with double-dollars: $\text{\begin{array}{ccc}A&\rightarrow &B\\......\end{array}}$. This isn't ideal, but it works for basic diagrams.

Comment: @user1729 : thanks ! Can I still put some labels on the arrows ?

Comment: And how do you go down a line ?